# Interpreting qq-plot generated in R with a small sample of data

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have a small data sample with 10 firms and want to specify the distribution of their abnormal returns.

First thing I did was to create the following histogram which indicates, when i am not mistaken that the data might somehow be normal distributed but is left skewed, right?

[image]

Another test I made to get a visuale representation of the distribution is a qq-plot:
[image]

Based on the qq-plot I would not assume the data to be normally distributed or does the fitting of the dots on the line is somehow good enough to state the opposit?

Comment: If you have only 10 firms/observations histograms are not the best way in my opinion. Small sample are very sensitive to outliers. It appears to me that there is one observation which is very small.

Answer (score 1):

Your data are definitely left skewed, but fairly close to a normal distribution. Both plots show the same thing in two different ways.

The first plot shows you the distribution of your residuals as a histogram: the distribution of these points is not quite symmetric. You can try the `normcheck` function in the `s20x` package if you want a slightly cleaner visualisation of this that overlays the theoretical normal distribution.

The second plot with the dots and lines is slightly more informative but less intuitive. The line allows you to judge how close your observations (the dots) are to the theoretical normal distribution. The fact that some of the dots lie below the line on the lefthand side suggests that some of the points are further left than one would expect under a normal distribution given a large sample size. Ideally, all the points lie on the line.

Depending on your reasons for fitting the model a slight left skew like you have may not be a problem. If you are fitting the model, determine if there is a relationship between some covariates and a response. Then you can rely on the "central limit theorem", which basically says that given enough data points the underlying distribution will tend towards normal - i.e. don't worry about it in this case.

However, if you are building the model for prediction you are in a little bit of a predicament as the predictions are no longer going to be quite accurate. This is because the assumption that your errors are normally distributed has not been met. You can still salvage this though; you will just need to try a different model. Here are a few options:

1. Log your response variable.
2. Try a robust regression technique that is less susceptible to these issues.
3. Quantile regression which makes no assumptions about the underlying error distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, André! I also prepared the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to test H0 = data are normaly distributed. However I got a very small p value which indicates that i have to reject H0 and thus assume that the data are not normaly distributed. Isn't this somehow inconsistent with the statement that the data are fairly normal distributed?

Comment: It is incongruous. However, it is a result of formal tests of assumptions being overly sensitive. Try running this bit of code a dozen or so times: `hist(rnorm(50, 0, 10))` It is sampling from a true normal distribution but what you will find is that with a small sample size that you often get non-normal shapes and ones with skew. The underlying distribution is normal though. The tests are very sensitive to deviations from the underlying distribution, while in practice the models we fit are typically quite robust to these deviations.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. So basically the main issue here is, that my data sample just contains 10 firms, right? Do you have some further information regarding the problems of small data samples? :)

Comment: It looks like your data has a lot more observations than just 10 as the histogram shows the frequency of residuals in different bins; at a guess around 50. Whether this is small or not depends on a couple things: 1) The size of the effect you are trying to estimate. As sample size increases the ability of your model to detect small differences increases; whether or not small differences are of practical significance depends on your question of interest. 2) related to the first issue the more effects you are trying to estimate the more degrees of freedom you need with each effect eating up one.

Comment: There are more issues than just that though. See this (https://garstats.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/small-sample-sizes/) for more information.